# How do you edit text in a text box which has been inserted from a building block?

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox

I'm trying to insert text boxes from a building block with a for loop (Word). I've taken a snippet of the code which tries to create 3 text boxes with text "Appendix A" - "Appendix C".

I can't find a way to select the text box being added in an iteration of the loop.

```
Dim objTextBox As Object
Dim i As Integer

For i = 65 To 67

  Set objTextBox = Application.Templates( _ 
    ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Path & "\" & ActiveDocument.Name _ 
    ).BuildingBlockEntries("Appendix Text Box") 

  With objTextBox
    .Insert Where:=Selection.Range _
    , RichText:=True
  End With

  ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Text Box 2")).Select ' Selects the wrong text box.
  Selection.TypeText Text:="Appendix " & Chr(i)

Next
```

I've tried editing the text from objTextBox as well such as using TextFrame, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

```
objTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Appendix " & Chr(i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help you to look up the documentation for objects, methods, or properties that you don't understand. You can access this directly from the VBE simply by pressing F1. Alternatively, you can press F2 to display the Object Browser which will show you the events, methods, and properties of an object.

The [`BuildingBlock.Insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.buildingblock.insert) method returns a `Range` object that represents the contents of the building block inserted into the document. From that you can access the `ShapeRange`, but you cannot use the shape name as the id because it will be different for each text box that you insert.

```
Dim bBlock As BuildingBlock
Dim i As Integer
Dim tbRange As Range

For i = 65 To 67
    Set bBlock = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("Appendix Text Box")
    Set tbRange = bBlock.Insert(Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True)
    tbRange.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Appendix " & Chr(i)
Next
```